# Removing Sand from blacktop

Tags: cleaning, removal, asphalt

Recently my son's friends played a prank on our house. Specifically they dumped bags of sand on our basketball court in the backyard so that they could pretend to have a beach party. I am not sure how I will remove the sand now though, I was wondering if anyone could help me with this strange problem?

Comment: I don't see how it's your problem. They played the "prank", they get to clean it up.

Right?

Comment: Perhaps a ShopVac?

Answer (score 4):

A number of guilty teenagers, a broom or two, a shovel, a wheelbarrow.

Your job is to point out when the job has not been completed to your satisfaction, until it has been. Your job is definitely NOT cleaning up the sand.

Comment: Also give them a shop vac to get all the sand out of the surface. When they are done, congratulate them with a new basketball!